# How to get a part of a BLOB field

Tags: c++, sqlite

I try to get a part of a BLOB field in a select query, e.g.,
    `subblobstr(BLOB_DATA,2,3)

The code is as follows, and it can be compiled correctly, but it doesn't work: subblobstr(BLOB_DATA,2,3) still gets the same result just like substr(BLOB_DATA,2,3).

Hope someone can give me some advice.  Thanks in advanced.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "sqlite3ext.h"
 SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT1

void subblobstr(sqlite3_context* ctx, int argc, sqlite3_value* argv[])
{
   const char* blobdata;
   int blob_len, start, slen;

   blobdata = (char*)sqlite3_value_blob(argv[0]);
   blob_len = sqlite3_value_bytes(argv[0]);
   start = sqlite3_value_int(argv[1]) - 1; 
   slen = sqlite3_value_int(argv[2]);
   sqlite3_result_blob(ctx, blobdata + start, slen, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
}

int sqlite3SubBlobStrInit(sqlite3 *db){
  sqlite3_create_function(db, "subblobstr",3,SQLITE_ANY, 0, subblobstr, 0, 0);
  return 0;
}

int sqlite3_extension_init(
  sqlite3 *db, 
  char **pzErrMsg,
  const sqlite3_api_routines *pApi
){
  SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2(pApi)
  return sqlite3SubBlobStrInit(db);
}
```

**[UPDATE]**
 The structure of table:

```
 cid         name        type
----------  ----------  ----------
  0           NAME         TEXT
  1           BLOB_DATA    BLOB
```

BLOB_DATA is a blob type field, which contains a single 20MB string, and I just want to  display the first few bytes of the string, however, substr function doesn't work because it will stop at the first NULL byte in the BLOB_DATA, so I have to write the function above to solve the problem.

The table contains lots of data, but substr(BLOB_DATA,1,10) returns a single digit at most.
[image]

Quote from CL:
"that the values in the table are strings, in which case you should convert them into blobs with something like this:"
  `UPDATE MyTable SET blob_data = CAST(blob_data AS BLOB)`

After running SQL statement above, sqlite shell will crash.(SQLite version 3.7.15.2  Win7) 
, so I use SQLite Databasebut Browser to set the type of BLOB_DATA first(BLOB), then substr(BLOB_DATA,1,10) still return 1 digit.

Comment: Your `subblobstr` is identical with `substr`. And neither `x'bc0'` nor `x'b'` are valid blobs. It appears you wrote `subblobstr` to solve some problem, but you haven't said what that problem is.

Answer (score 1):

`substr` works just fine with null bytes in blobs:

```sql
sqlite> CREATE TABLE MyTable(MyBlob);
sqlite> INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (x'aabbccddeeff');
sqlite> INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (x'221100221100');
sqlite> INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (x'123456');
sqlite> INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (x'ff1100223456');
sqlite> SELECT quote(MyBlob) FROM MyTable WHERE substr(MyBlob, 2, 3) = x'110022';
X'221100221100'
X'FF1100223456'
```

Your problem is either

- that the values in the table are strings, in which case you should convert them into blobs with something like this:

  ```sql
  UPDATE MyTable SET blob_data = CAST(blob_data AS BLOB)
  ```
- or that you are trying to display the returned value, which is likely to convert it into a string.
  Use functions like `quote` or `length` to check whether the returned blob values are correct.